# How to auto-rotate the screen using Yoga 900's accelerometer?

Tags: linux, dbus, accelerometer

The Yoga 900 has an accelerometer which should allow auto-rotation behavior.

On installing
https://github.com/hadess/iio-sensor-proxy (Linux*, LightDM) it is possible to run monitor-sensor.

```
➜  ~ monitor-sensor
    Waiting for iio-sensor-proxy to appear
+++ iio-sensor-proxy appeared
=== Has accelerometer (orientation: undefined)
=== Has ambient light sensor (value: 0.000000, unit: lux)
    Accelerometer orientation changed: normal
    Light changed: 49.999999 (lux)
    Light changed: 79.999998 (lux)
    Accelerometer orientation changed: left-up
    Accelerometer orientation changed: normal
    Accelerometer orientation changed: left-up
    Accelerometer orientation changed: bottom-up
```

With `iio-sensor-proxy` the data is made available on dbus. It has the form:

```
signal time=1479631365.562013 sender=:1.15 -> destination=(null destination) serial=449861 path=/com/ubuntu/Upstart; interface=com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6; member=EventEmitted
   string "dbus"
   array [
      string "SIGNAL=PropertiesChanged"
      string "BUS=system"
      string "INTERFACE=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"
      string "OBJPATH=/net/hadess/SensorProxy"
      string "SENDER=:1.4"
      string "ARG0=net.hadess.SensorProxy"
   ]
```

1. Is it possible to run a script that **only wakes up** on certain dbus events? Preferably I re-use an event loop in a daemon that already exists rather than building my own Python script or C program. Something like adding a file to `/etc/dbus.d/handlers/net/hadess/SensorProxy` would be really cool.
2. If I don't run `monitor-sensor` I do not seem messages appearing on dbus, even though `iio-sensor-proxy` is actually run. Are these messages only sent if someone is listening for them?

[*] Linux V 4.8.1-040801-generic #201610071031 SMP Fri Oct 7 14:34:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

PS: According to powertop when using `monitor-sensor`:

```
14.7 mW      1.5 ms/s       8.8        Process        dbus-monitor
```

The answer should describe the canonical way to handle this on Linux and be the most friendly solution from a battery usage perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Linux guru, but it seems like `dbus-monitor` is indeed the tool to use.

An answer to the post
[How to create a daemon which would be listening to dbus and fire script on message](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80145/17660) says :

> Based on
>   https://askubuntu.com/questions/150790/how-do-i-run-a-script-on-a-dbus-signal
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> interface=org.gnome.ScreenSaver
> member=ActiveChanged
>
> dbus-monitor --profile "interface='$interface',member='$member'" |
> while read -r line; do
>     echo $line | grep ActiveChanged && your_script_goes_here
> done
> ```
>
> Just stick that in **/etc/init.d/monitor-for-unlock**, make it
>   executable, and then make a soft link in rc2.d
>
> ```
> chmod +x /etc/init.d/monitor-for-unlock
> cd /etc/rc2.d
> ln -s /etc/init.d/monitor-for-unlock .
> ```

The article [Monitoring D-Bus](http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2009/02/dbus-monitor.html) adds :

> Probably the most powerful feature of dbus-monitor is the fact that
>   you are not limited to using just one watch expression at a time.  The
>   following example simultaneously monitors all 3 Tomboy signals and
>   uses awk to parse the output from dbus-monitor and display a
>   meaningful message.
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> OJECT="'org.gnome.Tomboy'"
> IFACE="'org.gnome.Tomboy.RemoteControl'"
> DPATH="'/org/gnome/Tomboy/RemoteControl'"
>
> WATCH1="type='signal', sender=${OJECT}, interface=${IFACE}, path=${DPATH}, member='NoteAdded'"
> WATCH2="type='signal', sender=${OJECT}, interface=${IFACE}, path=${DPATH}, member='NoteSaved'"
> WATCH3="type='signal', sender=${OJECT}, interface=${IFACE}, path=${DPATH}, member='NoteDeleted'"
>
> dbus-monitor "${WATCH1}" "${WATCH2}" "${WATCH3}" | \
> awk '
> /member=NoteAdded/ { getline; print "Created note " substr($2,7) }
> /member=NoteSaved/ { getline; print "Added note " substr($2,7) }
> /member=NoteDeleted/ { getline; print "Deleted note " substr($2,7) }
> '
> ```
>
> Here is the output generated when I clicked on the Tomboy icon to
>   create a new note, waited for the automatic save and then selected the
>   delete option to delete the note.
>
> ```
> $ ./test
> Created note //tomboy/3da026dc-f6ee-4637-8a94-bec6e2844824"
> Added note //tomboy/3da026dc-f6ee-4637-8a94-bec6e2844824"
> Deleted note //tomboy/3da026dc-f6ee-4637-8a94-bec6e2844824"
> ```

Comment: What is the influence of the while loop on the cpu? I assume it blocks on read, via a call to read(2). How is it exactly implemented?

Comment: I can't answer that, but it's easily tested.

Comment: I've implemented the above in the form of a script and in the form of a C daemon at [github](https://github.com/mrquincle/yoga-900-auto-rotate). The dbus-monitor solution calls **read** 27276 times in 2 minutes compared to 6 times with the C daemon. Seems a script like this is definitely not how it should be done from a battery perspective...

Comment: These methods were meant for debug rather than production. But it seems easy enough to create an event-driven script - [example](http://blog.foxxtrot.net/2010/05/detecting-removable-storage-mounts-using-dbus-and-python.html).

Comment: Mmm. I interpret your remark as "You should now try to use Python. It's all super easy." My intent with this question is to have people understand how to do this in the canonical way on Linux. Not trial and error.

Comment: See the technique in the article [Scripting D-Bus](http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2009/02/dbus-scripting.html). Its concluding sentence is: "While D-Bus was not really designed with shell scripting in mind, it is possible to use various utilities to access system and session data via D-Bus."

Comment: I don't think I'll get a canonical answer. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: I just want to chime in with my heartfelt thanks to @AnnevanRossum; I just compiled and installed the C daemon vanRossum wrote and linked to in the comment above, and 4 years later on a Yoga 9i it still works like a charm. Thank you thank you.

Comment: @GlenWhitney much appreciated. And now I'm reading back my comments... nothing wrong with scripting of course! I just wanted to know "the recommended way" to do things. My code at https://github.com/mrquincle/yoga-900-auto-rotate is just one step towards what I think should be done, but actually, true desktop developers should take a look and implement it in a way that fits their system.